# How to find where nextcloud directory is in apache server running on ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, nextcloud

I have ubuntu server running nextcloud "File sharing app"

I installed a program called Transmission bittorrent.

My problem is bittorrent is saving the downloaded files outside nextcloud directory, for that nextcloud can't see the files, for that I'm searching on folder called "Movies" inside nextcloud to change the defult bittorrent saving location

I tried to search on it by this command  `find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "Movies"`
But it doesn't give any result.

I searched for nextcloud directory and I found it here `/var/www/html/3rdparty/nextcloud/`
But when listing all files ls -a it's only show lognormalizer file!

What I'm doing wrong, How I can find the folder "Movies"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the file by using this command

```
sudo find / -type d -name Movies 2>/dev/null
```